# How can I assign a value based on 2 conditions in R?

Tags: r, switch-statement

first the data, then my question:

```
df <- data.frame(Z=c(1,2,3),Y=c(2,3),A=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
df
Z Y A
1 2 1
2 2 2
3 2 3
1 3 4
2 3 5
3 3 6
```

I am using R and would like to generate a vector a with given vector `Z` and `Y`. Like if `(z1==1 & y1==2)`, then `a1=1`, if `(z3==3 & y1==2)`, then `a1=3`....If we only have one condition (`Z` or `Y`), I could generate `A` with switch function, however, how could I generate `A` with `Z` and `Y`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly the answer is as follows. If I misunderstood then please correct me.

```
df <- data.frame(Z=c(1,2,3),Y=c(2,3),A=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))

df$A <- NA # Empty out A
# Re-create A
df$A[df$Z == 1 & df$Y == 2] <- 1
df$A[df$Z == 2 & df$Y == 2] <- 2
df$A[df$Z == 3 & df$Y == 2] <- 3
df$A[df$Z == 1 & df$Y == 3] <- 4
df$A[df$Z == 2 & df$Y == 3] <- 5
df$A[df$Z == 3 & df$Y == 3] <- 6

df <- df[order(df$A),]
df
```

> ```
>   Z Y A
> 1 1 2 1
> 5 2 2 2
> 3 3 2 3
> 4 1 3 4
> 2 2 3 5
> 6 3 3 6
> ```

Comment: I dont understand why the OP would like to generate the output again which is already present.

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli probably they want to show expected output.

Comment: @zx8754 Yeah but i could not even understand the logic to the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it in one call is to use ifelse function as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(Z=c(1,2,3),Y=c(2,3),A=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))

df$A <- ifelse(df$Z == 1 & df$Y == 2,1,
               ifelse(df$Z == 3 & df$Y == 2,3,
                      ifelse(df$Z > 1,5,8)))

  Z Y A
1 1 2 1
2 2 3 5
3 3 2 3
4 1 3 8
5 2 2 5
6 3 3 5
```

Answer (score 0):

As the number of conditions increases, if you're just looking at exact matches, it becomes more useful to use a lookup table for the results and merge them.  So we start with a lookup table as you've defined it

```
df.lookup <- data.frame(Z=c(1,2,3),Y=c(2,3),A=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

And let's say that we have a dataframe we want to populate

```
set.seed(17) # To get repeatable random numbers
df <- data.frame(Z=sample(1:3, 6, replace=T), Y=sample(2:3, 6, replace=T))
```

So we have

```
> df
  Z Y
1 1 2
2 3 2
3 2 3
4 3 2
5 2 2
6 2 2
> merge(df, df.lookup)
  Z Y A
1 1 2 1
2 2 2 5
3 2 2 5
4 2 3 2
5 3 2 3
6 3 2 3
```

The `merge` function will automatically select same-named columns, but you can specify the names if they are different, see `?merge` for more information.